# Duplicate Data in Left Join Query MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm querying for all books. Each book has many authors and many publishers. (Both authors and publishers can also belong to many books.) Here is my table schema with data:

```
CREATE TABLE book   (`id` int, `name` varchar(55));
CREATE TABLE author (`id` int, `name` varchar(55)); 
CREATE TABLE publisher (`id` int, `name` varchar(55));
CREATE TABLE book_author (`book_id` int, `author_id` int);
CREATE TABLE book_publisher (`book_id` int, `publisher_id` int);
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT book.title
  , GROUP_CONCAT(author.id SEPARATOR ';') AS authors 
  , GROUP_CONCAT(publisher.id SEPARATOR ';') AS publishers 
FROM book 
LEFT JOIN book_author ON book.id = book_author.book_id 
LEFT JOIN author ON book_author.author_id = author.id 
LEFT JOIN book_publisher ON book.id = book_publisher.book_id 
LEFT JOIN publisher ON book_publisher.publisher_id = publisher.id 
GROUP BY book.id
```

A book with 1 author and 1 publisher will return the author id twice. A book with 5 authors and 1 publisher will return the author id's twice (like this: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5). Any ideas on how to prevent the duplication of the authors and publishers?

Comment: Er, no it won't. But a book with two publishers would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the word distinct after `group_concat(` and before the field..

```
  GROUP_CONCAT(distinct author.id SEPARATOR ';') AS authors 
, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct publisher.id SEPARATOR ';') AS publishers
```

It's a [documented feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) of the GROUP_CONCAT function:

In full:

```
SELECT book.title
  , GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct author.id SEPARATOR ';') AS authors 
  , GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct publisher.id SEPARATOR ';') AS publishers 
FROM book 
LEFT JOIN book_author ON book.id = book_author.book_id 
LEFT JOIN author ON book_author.author_id = author.id 
LEFT JOIN book_publisher ON book.id = book_publisher.book_id 
LEFT JOIN publisher ON book_publisher.publisher_id = publisher.id 
GROUP BY book.id
```

There's two other ways that come to mind as well  neither of which I find as elegant.

1. a subquery getting the distict author's publishes per title and then use the group_concat
2. use inline selects (in the select) to get just the distinct author and publisher values list per book.